# Windows 7 selective internet access

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have a windows 7 pc thats connected to a wireless network. Windows says 'no internet access' yet the web browser works normally. However, some other apps arent getting network access. Any idea what the issue might be?
Edit:
the pc is on a domain and the browser does use a proxy and an automatic configuration script

Comment: What kind of applications arent getting network access?

Comment: Looks like problem at your provider DNS.

Comment: @Kamil Fitbit is one im aware of

Comment: What are you using for a browser?  Does it have any proxy server settings?  Are you using any firewall software?

Comment: @ernie browser is ie8 and no firewall

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you have access to the local network which means you can access your proxy but the Internet itself is not really reachable. All IE is showing you are the proxy cache results, not actual new data. To prove this go to a site that you can be fairly certain no one in your org has visited. I bet it won't work. Alternatively, disable the IE proxy and I bet nothing will work anymore.